# Multiple sending domains in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email, custom-domain

my client implemented SAP in his Marketing Cloud org, now he needs an additional sending domain (but not a new dedicated IP address), is it possibile to achieve this?
Must the new sending domain have the form of @email.mycompany.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we multiple sending domains in our single instance. When we want to add a new one we have to order a "Private Domain" which is a small additional cost for the domain to be authenticated. They will send you the instructions to delegate the DNS to them.

Thanks
Susan

Comment: Thanks Susan, but  private domain what IP Address will use? The same of SAP (dedicated IP) or a shared one?

Comment: We have more than one private IP in our account so we use sender profile and send classifications to define this. If you only have 1 private IP then it should automatically go over that IP - might be best to double check that with support when they are configuring the new private domain for you.